# browse all images with jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, repeat

I use this code to showing aone link when the mousemove event is lauched

```
$('#articlesdata\\:0\\:article-image').mousemove(function(){
                $('#articlesdata\\:0\\:article-suppr').show();
            });
```

I want to apply this code for all images , I means : `articlesdata\\:0\\:article-image` and `articlesdata\\:1\\:article-image` and `articlesdata\\:2\\:article-image`  and so on : all integer

how can I achieve that

thank you

Comment: i am not familiar with this selector syntax, and doing this much work on the dom on mouse move is not a good idea

Comment: @lbu don't worry, nobody is.

Comment: Where did you get this code? What is `:0`? Can you post your HTML?

Comment: That's just the id. He is using the correct syntax to select an element with `id="articlesdata:0:article-image"`

Comment: Your IDs seem overly complicated. Can you add your own classes to those elements instead, and keep the IDs shorter?

Comment: need to look at the $('').on('mousemove','img',function(e){} where $('') can be your outer container, something like this...

Answer (score 0):

use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) with `^`

> this selects id with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

try this

```
$([id^='articlesdata']).mousemove(function(){
   .....
```

Comment: sorry, I don't undesrtand what do you mean

Comment: you can go through the link... anyways this select all element with its ID starting with articlesdata.. try it out

Answer (score 0):

The best way to select them all would be to give them a common class.

```
<img class="article-image" id="articlesdata:0:article-image" src="foo1.jpg">
```

then select by class:

```
$(".article-image").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#" + this.id.replace('image','suppr')).show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("#" + this.id.replace('image','suppr')).hide();
});
```

or with your original code:

```
$(".article-image").mousemove(function(){
    $("#" + this.id.replace('image','suppr')).show();
})
```

Comment: I already tried class but when I hover one of them, all article-suppr  will appear : that I don't want

Comment: @atbegin-but That's because you did it wrong. did you even try my code? Notice how i'm doing it by both class AND id.

Comment: I tested it with `alert("#" + this.id.replace('image','suppr'));` it return me `#articlesdata:0:article-suppr`  but I need to put \\  before each `:` to be selected;

Comment: @atbegin-but That can be done with a `.replace` or `.split()` and `.join()`

Comment: I tested **"#" + this.id.replace('image','suppr').replace(':','\\:')**  but it return : **#articlesdata\:0:article-suppr** while I need **'#articlesdata\\:0\\:article-suppr**

Comment: you have to escape the \ too. \\\\

Comment: it replace me only the first **:**

Comment: you need to use the global flag. `/:/g,'\\\\:'`

Comment: did you wrap `/:/g` in quotes? it doesn't belong in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your images have id like `articlesdata\\:0\\:article-image` or `articlesdata:0:article-image`, you might do something like this :

```
$('img').mousemove(function(){
     if (/article-image$/.test(this.id)) {
         $(document.getElementById(this.id.replace(/-image$/, '-suppr'))).show();
     }
});
```

But instead of `mousemove`, I would recommend to use `mouseenter`.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ajozax/1/edit)